# How do I store app data using Android KeyChain and will that value persist even if the app was deleted

Tags: android, keychain, persist

I need to keep a counter, but I need it to persist if the app was deleted, and I cannot put it in the external memory.  I have been told I could use KeyChain, but I have not found a basic example of storing app data, its all been for authenticating.  Is it possible to use the KeyChain to store app data, and how? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, entries in the Android keychain are tied to the app and are removed when the app is unisntalled. If not, that's a bug in the keychain that needs to be fixed.